# I can't get this simple maths quiz to work. Answer is always wrong

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint

stats = {'correct': 0, 'wrong': 0}
correct = 0

for i in range(10):
    n1 = randint(1, 10)
    n2 = randint(1, 10)
    prod = n1 * n2

    ans = input("What's %dx%d?" % (n1, n2))
    if ans == prod:
       print ('Your answer is correct. Well done.')
       stats['correct'] += 1
    else:
        print (('Your answer is wrong. I am afraid the answer is %d.') % prod)
        stats['wrong'] += 1

print (("\nI asked you 10 questions. You got %d of them right.") % correct)
print ("Well done!")
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. you need to be more specific. what have you tried, what should it be, where's the problem in the code. dumping a load of code and saying 'fix this' isn't a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer received from the input is a string.

```
    if ans == str(prod):
```

Should do the trick...